# GDB on OS X 10.15 (Catalina) stuck at first execution

Tags: macos, debugging, terminal, gdb

I know many have already assessed GDB and recent versions of OS X aren't bet buddies and people should really be looking at LLDB, but still.

I managed to CodeSign GDB after the installation of GDB from brew, and I am now trying to actually use it.

Problem is on my OS X 10.15 (Catalina) something happens and it get stuck when is run the debugging of my C compiled app.
I need to

```
killall -9 gdb
```

from another terminal to close  the stuck GDB.

If I start GDB again in the same terminal session, and then i run the app in GDB, it works.

This behaviour appears to repeat every time I try to start GDB from a new terminal session.

Has anyone experienced the same and what should be looking at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a random issue, GDB and MacOS simply aren't good buddies.